# How to index a table using Apache Ignite RDD from Scala?

Tags: indexing, apache-spark, ignite

I'm trying to find a clear example how to index a table using **Ignite RDD** from Scala, but couldn't find anything.
Could somebody please give simple and clear example how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: I would like to know why my question was downvoted. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to add indexed type configuration to the corresponding cache configuration:

```
val ccfg = new CacheConfiguration[Object, Object]()
ccfg.setName(PARTITIONED_CACHE_NAME)
ccfg.setIndexedTypes(classOf[String], classOf[Entity])
```

The `Entity` class should have corresponding annotations. You can refer to https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-queries for more details.

Then you can create an `IgniteRDD` instance and save your data:

```
val cache: IgniteRDD[String, Entity] = ic.fromCache(PARTITIONED_CACHE_NAME)
cache.savePairs(...)
```

And, finally, you can query the indexed data using the `sql(...)` method on IgniteRDD:

```
val df = cache.sql("select field1, field2 from Entity where field3 = ?", "value3")
```